# Access Angular property of a DOM element from Cypress

Tags: angular, dom, cypress, angular-template

I have an Angular application where I have a container like this:

```
<div id="my-container" [data-version]="version$ | async">
```

I have added the `data-version` property specifically for my Cypress tests, so I will know certain nuances of what I need a test to do.

However, I am having difficulty finding the right incantation to access that value. Here is what I have tried:

First, let's call the above line flavor `A` and this version without brackets flavor `B`:

```
<div id="my-container" data-version="version$ | async">
```

Then I have 3 flavors of Cypress I have tried:

```
cy.get('#my-container')
  .its('data-version') // Flavor 1
  .then((version) => {
    console.log(version);
  }

cy.get('#my-container')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-version') // Flavor 2
  .then((version) => {
    console.log(version);
  }

cy.get('#my-container')
  .invoke('attr', 'data-version') // Flavor 3
  .then((version) => {
    console.log(version);
  }
```

The results:

- 1A: Cypress balks
- 2A: Cypress balks
- 3A: Cypress balks
- 1B: Cypress does not find the attribute
- 2B: Cypress finds the literal 'version$ | async'
- 2C: Cypress finds the literal 'version$ | async'

Question: Is there a way to retrieve an Angular property from Cypress?

Comment: Flavor B is a no-go, the expression wont be evaluated and you simply bind a string.
Mind trying with: `[attr.data-version]="version$ | async"`?

Comment: Excellent @Jota.Toledo! With that change to the HTML, then 2A (`should`) and 3A (`invoke`) both work. Interestingly 1A (`its`) did not find the attribute (I even tried `its(attr.data-version)`).

Please post your comment as an answer so I can credit it to you! Extra points (at least in spirit) if you can point me to any docs on that `attr` notation.

Comment: leaved an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flavor *B* is a no-go, the expression wont be evaluated and you simply bind a string.

You should use the following syntax:

```
[attr.data-version]="version$ | async"
```

This is documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets)